# Open accordeon panel with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, anchor

Would there be a simple way to open an anchor with the Foundation's accordion?

My simple code (available on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWmPZV))

```
<a href="#panel1" class="link">Open the first panel</a>
<a href="#panel2" class="link">Open the second panel</a>


<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      I would start in the open state, due to using the `is-active` state class.
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      I would start in the open state, due to using the `is-active` state class.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have gone through the Foundation's documentation, but there is no mention of a pre-designed system.

Could someone help me with this kind of system? I confess I do not know how to do it.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the jQuery UI library this additional code will work for your example:

```
$(".accordion").accordion();
$('a').on('click',function() {
  $('.accordion').accordion("option", "active", $(this).index());
})
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZQxWd

Personally, I'd add a specific ID to that accordion and refer to it using that instead of the class of accordion.  Also, I'd nail down the links to use by a class instead of catching all links as I've done in the working example code.